# How to measure the component startup time in a Spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, jvm

How do I properly measure the startup time of a Spring web application, grouped by component?

Ideally, I'd like to get both system information (such as class loading time, by package) and component information (bean/application loading), along with a timeline showing the loading times of each bean/component/class/package.

The [Chrome Timeline](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) is a nice example for what I'm looking for.

VisualVM/JConsole profilers show method times and do not group anything, which makes them unsuitable for what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now the best answer I could find was to use the information in Brendan Gregg's [Java Flame Graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-06-12/java-flame-graphs.html) post. It's not exactly simple, but it's a start.

The following instructions only work on Linux:

1. Clone [lightweight-java-profiler](https://github.com/dcapwell/lightweight-java-profiler)

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/dcapwell/lightweight-java-profiler
   ```
2. Build it:

   ```
   cd lightweight-java-profiler
   make
   cd ..
   ```
3. Start the application with the additional `-agentpath` switch, then quit it when you're done profiling:

   ```
   java -jar -agentpath:lightweight-java-profiler/build-64/liblagent.so /path/to/your-webapp.jar
   ```

   After this, you should find a file called `traces.txt` in the current directory.
4. Download Brendan Gregg's FlameGraph tools:

   ```
   git clone http://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph
   ```
5. Execute the provided scripts to convert the trace file into a SVG file:

   ```
   cd FlameGraph
   ./stackcollapse-ljp.awk < ../traces.txt | ./flamegraph.pl > ../traces.svg
   ```
6. Open the SVG file in Firefox ; the X axis is the number of samples (100% corresponds to the total profiling time), and method calls are stacked on the Y axis:

   [image: Example generated flame graph]